# Changing element width from px to %

Tags: javascript, jquery

As referred to in the title, I want change element width from px to % in jQuery.

How should I do?

Comment: Change WHAT element? While I am not the one who down voted your post. But you should at least show the expected result or explain what you're trying to do in your question.

Comment: `element.css('width', '20%');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a math question:

> Element Width (px) / Container Width (px) * 100 = Element Width (%)

Say you have an element that's 20px wide, inside a container that's 40px wide:

> 20 / 40 * 100 = 50

Means that 50% equals 20px for that element.

So a simple function that accepts a jQuery element/object as a parameter would be:

```
function convert($e) {
    var newWidth = parseInt($e.css('width'), 10) /  parseInt($e.parent().css('width'), 10) * 100;
    $e.css('width', newWidth + '%');
}
```

You might want to extend this so you can pass in the parent element as well (in case the direct parent is not the relative reference element).

---

After clicking the Convert button, you'll see the width change from px to %:

```js
function convert($e) {
    var newWidth = parseInt($e.css('width'), 10) /  parseInt($e.parent().css('width'), 10) * 100;
    $e.css('width', newWidth + '%');
}
```

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
}

#c {
  width: 40px;
}

#a {
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c">
  <div id="a"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="convert($('#a'))">Convert</button>
```